# What does "process.argv[2]" mean in this Node fs write function?

Tags: node.js, fs, writefile

Just started learning Node and I'm reviewing exercises from class today. Can't remember what the "process.argv[2]" refers to when writing a new file using fs. I'm thinking [0] would refer to "node", and [1] would refer to the name of the file that you're creating ("log.txt"), so what's this code referring to at [2]? This code works fine and outputs "Success!", btw, just trying to understand it a bit better. Thanks!

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFile("log.txt", process.argv[2], function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log("Success!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Kind of but not totally.

Comment: What exactly become clearer, and what are the remaining questions then? Have you checked the whole thread, and not just the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the arguments you supply when you launch your app with node. It starts in 2 because the first two parameters are the command and the file.

`process.argv = ['node', 'yourscript.js', ...]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a holdover from the early days of UNIX and the C language, a very useful holdover.

If you run your nodejs program by saying this to your command line

```
node whatever whatelse
```

Then `process.argv[2]` contains the value `whatelse`. The words on the command line end up in that `argv` array numbered from zero.

In your example, it looks like you will use

```
node myprogram.js whatever
```

to write the word "whatever" to the file called `log.txt`. Why? the code you showed mentions `process.argv[2]` in the second parameter to `fs.writeFile()`. That parameter supplies the information you want written to the file.

Comment: Thank you for the example. So when writing a new file as in my code, what value does "process.argv[2]" contain? If I understand, [0] is "node", and [1] is "index.js" (the name of the file the "fs.writeFile" code is in), but I'm not understanding what the exact value of [2] would be. To get this code to run and actually write the "log.txt" file, I just need to enter "node index.js" (which are positions [0] and [1]). So is the value of [2] "fs"? or "fs.writeFile"? or "log.txt"?